# Loadrunner agents under Windows and Linux

Tags: linux, loadrunner

I'm going to perform load testing with LR. The controller has been installed under windows and due to the machines shortage, the agents have been installed both windows and linux. The questions are:

1) Does LR support this mode as I concern if windows and linux can communicate with each other?
2) If so, which configuration about linux should be edited? Note: under windows, I edited two registery keys: TcpTimeWaitDelay and MaxUserPort.

Any tips for the questions will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

(1) LoadRunner has supported UNIX based Load Generators since the very first version of LoadRunner.   The Windows based controller has been able to communicate with UNIX (and now LINUX) based load generators since version 5.02.   This is a well established model for the use of Load Generators.   This is a socket service based communication between a Windows based controller and the LINUX based load generators....which is the same model also used between the Windows based controller and the Windows based Load Generators.

Linux Load Generators are not considered promiscuous, in that they do not support every protocol.   The Windows based load generators do support every protocol.   It is also the case that the Windows based load generators are the "reference" generators for support, so if you need to call with an issue be prepared to contrast the performance of the Windows based load generators with the LINUX based ones for support purposes.

(2)  Can you answer why you edited these values?   This would be an unconventional installation with the manual editing of registry keys so if you could explain why you did this it may help us to understand what you are trying to achieve and whether you need to make such modifications to other hosts.

Comment: Thanks James for the quick reply. I explain question #2. 

1) The reason for editing two windows register keys: "TcpTimeWaitDelay" and "MaxUserPort" is that I encountered the error “Error: Failed to connect to server "192.168.1.100:2060": [10061] Connection refused” many times. Doing so fix this error.

2) I ask for linux tips because during LR run, only linux agents failed to initialize frequently. So  I want to know if some configuration should be done under linux like windows. Note: 
my LR ENV includes 7 windows agents and 3 linux agents.

Comment: Given the nature of these two registry keys I would be looking at overloaded load generators.  As to why the linux agent is not initializing, agent software is very version specific to vendor and version of OS.  So, if you are experimenting with an off version of make then you should expect odd behavior.   I would also recommend opening a case with HP support if you are a fully supported OS and version.

Comment: Thanks James for the detailed reply. My linux version is: centos 6.3 final. Will open a case to HP.

Comment: Double check our LINUX version before contacting HP support and reconcile to a supported vendor and version if necessary, such as moving to actual RedHat Enterprise xx.xx to check for differences between that and the Centos build.